# Sidebar widget: Randomly select text from a given set

Tags: plugins, widgets, text

I have a sidebar text widget, which displays a nice quote that's related to the blog contents.

I change the quote every now and then, And I'm looking for a way to create a set of quotes and display one of them at random.

Is there a plugin for that?

Comment: Did a search for 'Random Quotes' in the plugin repo not find anything that was suitable? [This](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/quotes-collection/) looks good to me...

Comment: @m0r7if3r Yup, that's what I was looking for. Care to put it as an answer, so I can accept and upvote it?

Comment: Submitted answer, glad I could help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plugin repository contains a few options that you could use. At a glance [this one](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/quotes-collection/) looks promising.